# SFINAE: ambiguous overload if called with no arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae

Consider the following typical SFINAE test function (it checks if a type has a `begin()` member function)

```
    template <class> constexpr bool
has_begin_member (...) { return false; }

    template <class T> constexpr bool
has_begin_member (decltype (std::declval <T>().begin ())* = 0) { 
    return true;
}
```

I can call it with an argument:

```
has_begin_member <int> (0); // yields false
```

but without any arguments:

```
has_begin_member <int> (); // compilation error
```

it leads to the following ambiguity:

```
error: call of overloaded 'has_begin_member()' is ambiguous
note: candidates are:
note: constexpr bool has_begin_member(...)
note: constexpr bool has_begin_member(decltype (declval<T>().begin())*)
```

Why doesn't the "ellipsis trick" work in that case?

Edit: full program:

```
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

    template <class> constexpr bool
has_begin_member (...) { return false; }

    template <class T> constexpr bool
has_begin_member (decltype (std::declval <T>().begin ())* = 0) { 
    return true;
}


static_assert (!has_begin_member <int> (0), "broken");
static_assert (has_begin_member <std::vector <int>> (0), "broken");

static_assert (!has_begin_member <int> (), "broken");
static_assert (has_begin_member <std::vector <int>> (), "broken");

    int 
main (){}
```

Compilation:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -o toto ./toto.cpp
./toto.cpp:17:58: error: call of overloaded 'has_begin_member()' is ambiguous
./toto.cpp:17:58: note: candidates are:
./toto.cpp:5:5: note: constexpr bool has_begin_member(...) [with <template-parameter-1-1> = std::vector<int>]
./toto.cpp:8:5: note: constexpr bool has_begin_member(decltype (declval<T>().begin())*) [with T = std::vector<int>; decltype (declval<T>().begin()) = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >]
```

Comment: g++ (GCC) 4.7.1 20120721 (prerelease)

Comment: I thought that looked like a GCC diagnostic, but it works fine for me with G++ 4.5, 4.6, 4.7, 4.8 and with Clang++ too. Please show a complete example program that demonstrates the error, I'm obviously not testing the same thing as you.

Comment: Aha, `has_begin_member <int> ();` works fine, it's only `has_begin_member <std::vector<int>> ();` that fails

Comment: Yes, sorry, I posted a bit quickly!

Comment: Better way to write the `true` overload: `template<class T> constexpr auto has_begin_member(T const* p) -> decltype(p->begin(), bool()){ return true; }` and call with `has_begin_member<T>(0)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the `has_begin_member<int>()` case the second overload is not viable because template argument substitution fails, so only the first overload is viable, so no ambiguity.

For the `has_begin_member<std::vector<int>>()` case substitution succeeds so there are two viable functions.

13.3.2 [over.match.viable]:

> - If there are *m* arguments in the list, all candidate functions having exactly *m* parameters are viable.
> - A candidate function having fewer than *m* parameters is viable only if it has an ellipsis in its parameter
>     list (8.3.5). For the purposes of overload resolution, any argument for which there is no corresponding
>     parameter is considered to “match the ellipsis” (13.3.3.1.3) .
> - A candidate function having more than *m* parameters is viable only if the *(m+1)*-st parameter has a
>     default argument (8.3.6). For the purposes of overload resolution, the parameter list is truncated
>     on the right, so that there are exactly *m* parameters.

In this case *m* is zero, the first overload is viable (by the second bullet) and the second overload is also viable (by the third bullet) but for the purposes of overload resolution the parameter with a default argument is ignored, and so the best viable functions is found by comparing:

```
template<> constexpr bool has_begin_member<vector<int>>(...);
template<> constexpr bool has_begin_member<vector<int>>();
```

Which is obviously ambiguous, just like this is:

```
int f(...);
int f();

int i = f();  // error
```

There is no conversion sequence needed to call either function, so they cannot be ranked in terms of which has a "better conversion sequence" than the other (using the rules in 13.3.3.2 [over.ics.rank],) which means they are ambiguous.

Comment: Okay, because in that case there is no conversion, so the ellipsis thing doesn't play any role, right?

Comment: Yes, see the extra example I added to the end of my answer.